# Laurent series for $e^\frac{1}{z}$ about $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function, laurent-series

What I've currently done is Taylor expansion for $e^z$
$$e^z = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!}$$
And $\frac{1}{z}$ substitution
$$e^\frac{1}{z} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \frac{1}{z^k}$$
But this substitution leads to expansion about $z=\infty$
How can I get expansion about $z=0$?

Comment: Recall that $1/z= z^{-1}$- So you have $$\sum_{n=- \infty}^0 \frac{1}{n!}z^n$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But you *did* get the Laurent series about $0$:$$1+\frac1z+\frac1{2!z^2}+\frac1{3!z^3}\cdots$$

Comment: I don't clearly understand why. Is it because $e^z$ expansion about 0 converges everywhere and thus $\frac{1}{z}$ substitution doesn't change the domain of convergence?

Comment: @JDoe It's exactly that (except that it doesn't converge when $z=0$, of course).

Comment: Thanks! So the expansions at zero and at infinity are same. Haven't ever seen such a thing :)